# Finished garage ceiling for storage: 2 x 6 spanning 11' 6" - 16 on center?

Tags: ceiling, garage

Span is 11' 6" and I'm wanting to use 2 x 6

I'm wanting to create storage in my single car garage by adding a ceiling and adding storage above with a pull-down ladder. I'm doing the work myself but want to do it right to have it inspected. All the span tables I read say that I should probably use a 2 x 8 for the joists but where the outside (exterior) wall top plate meets the roof isn't a lot of space (wanted to maintain 9 ft ceiling). I was looking to notch out the 2 x 6 on one end to rest on the top plate then using ceiling joist holders on the other. Would I be better off lowering the ceiling height to account for the clearance (running 2 x 8's) and having a ledger board on both sides of the span?

Do I have any play in what type of lumber/grade/joist hanger/nails to use 2 x 6?

Comment: why aren't both ends the same?

Comment: sorry. I misspoke. yeah the other side would sit on the top plate of that load bearing wall of my house (interior wall of my garage). the way it looked confused me but I just went up there and looked at it. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

You're residential so your storage loads should be 40 psf to match the interior floor live load. For the dead load, lets assume 5 psf and 11' 6" true span from inside of wall to inside of wall with floor joists bearing on top.

Yes, the tables are correct, you would need a 2x8 at 16" oc. This is for Hem-fir #2 graded lumber.

### The good news - You have other options

You can change any combination of the materials, spacing, and joist counts

1. Double 2x6, DF (Doug-fir) #2 or HF #1, @ 16" oc
2. Double 2x6, HF #2 @ 12" oc

Comment: Ah ok. So double them up. Great point. Does notching out a part of the 2x 6 to fit that space affect the load? Is there a way to figure out how much of the 2x6 I'm allowed to notch out while still maintaining load? Thanks for answering

Comment: Most typical lumber at the home improvement store is going to be HF#2 and so to use that you have to BOTH double up and go to 12" oc. DO NOT NOTCH THE BOTTOM. You can remove material from the end of the joist and upward at a 45 degree angle with no reduction. Deflection is controlling, not bearing on the wall. You can bear just 2-1/2" on the end wall. Does that combination give you enough?

Comment: there currently is a level 2x4 running across that almost entirely fits in the space. maybe notched out less than 1/2 inch. Does that work?

Comment: also I'm in California so I think I read in another thread about seismic considerations but considering my house was built in the 40's whats the point?

Comment: If a 2x4 fits you're fine, just remove the top outer part of the 2x6 to fit your roof slope. The consideration re seismic is that you are adding load that will apply further loads to your, as you noted, very under strength (to today's standards) lateral system. You said that you want it inspected, I suggest talking with your local building department, usually they are very helpful. You'll need their approval anyway, might as well get it before you build rather than risk having to change something later.

Answer (score 1):

The Code requires a live load of 20 lbs. per square foot for limited attic storage and 30 lbs. per square foot for attic storage with fixed stairs. (See IRC Table 301.5)

Limited storage is defined as an attic space that has trusses. (See Table 301.5, footnote “g”.) I doubt that is your condition. Therefore, you need to design to 30 lbs. per square foot, unless you’re going to store stacks of books or other heavy objects.

A No. 2 Doug-Fir 2x6 spanning 11’-6” can support the following:

1) At 12” oc = 50 psf
2) At 16” oc = 37 psf

You’ll have a dead load of:

1) 3/8” plywood floor =    1.2 psf
2) 2x6’s at 16” oc =         2.0 psf
3) 1/2” plywood ceiling = 1.5 psf
———————————————-
Total Dead Load =            4.7 psf

Therefore, your 2x6’s at 16” oc can support a live load of: 37-4.7 = 32.3 psf

I’d use 2x6’s at 16” on center.

The Code allows you to notch the end of the joist at the bearing wall a maximum of 1/4 the height of the joist. (See IRC Figure R502.8) Therefore, you can notch 1.37” from the top of your 2x6 joists.

That is probably not enough in your situation. I’d talk to the Building Official and explain that you only need 1.5” of bearing, so you’d like to notch 1.37” at the 1.5” bearing point. Therefore, the remainder of the 2x6’s could be notched more without violating Figure R502.8. I’d guess he’d agree.